# Based on available resources, how to construct a dependency graph in Go?

Tags: algorithm, go, data-structures, graph

For example:

**Step 1:**
There are four registers

> [r1, r2, r3, r4]

**Step 2 (Input):**
Sample instructions are:

```
g1[r1, r3]
g2[r4]
g3[r3]
g4[r2]
g5[r1, r3]
g6[r1]
```

g1[r1, r3] means registers r1 and r3 are being used by instruction g1. 
So any other instruction with r1 or r3 or both can only be executed after g1 i.e. g3 because it is dependent.

However, register for g2 is spare so it can be executed in parallel to g1 as it is independent. After the execution of g1, g3 also becomes independent.

**Step 3 (not required):**
Based on above instructions, a sample visualization of the graph can be (drawn manually):

[image: A sample visualization of the graph]

**Step 4:**
Go code will look like this:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/twmb/algoimpl/go/graph"
)

func main() {
  g := graph.New(graph.Directed)

  instruction := make(map[string]graph.Node, 0)
  instruction["g1"] = g.MakeNode()
  instruction["g2"] = g.MakeNode()
  instruction["g3"] = g.MakeNode()
  instruction["g4"] = g.MakeNode()
  instruction["g5"] = g.MakeNode()
  instruction["g6"] = g.MakeNode()

  for key, node := range instruction {
    *node.Value = key
  }
  // Connect dependent edges
  g.MakeEdge(instruction["g1"], instruction["g3"])
  g.MakeEdge(instruction["g1"], instruction["g5"])
  g.MakeEdge(instruction["g3"], instruction["g5"])
  g.MakeEdge(instruction["g5"], instruction["g6"])

  sorted := g.TopologicalSort()
  for i := range sorted {
      fmt.Println(*sorted[i].Value)
  }
}
```

### Issue:

Currently, I am connecting dependent edges manually. But if the number of input instructions increases the manual connections won't be possible. So I want to know, how to write the code that will automatically construct the dependency graph based on Input (Step 1 and Step 2).

It will be a DAG and Topological sort will be used to sort the order of execution and the output will be

**Step 5 (output):**
A sample output of above code (could be in different form):

> g1, g2, g4, g3, g5, g6

Answer (score 0):

Would [this](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Go) Topological sorter in Go from Rosetta Code help?

Comment: It seems that output is not correct. For input: `g1 r1 r3       
g2 r4
g3 r3
g4 r2
g5 r1 r3
g6 r1`                                                                      
The output is: `Order: [r4 g2 r2 g4 r3 g3 r1 g6 g5 g1]` where g3 should be between g1 and g5